# Super-höfliche Form der Kontaktanfragen auf Sozialen Netzwerken?

Tags: politeness

Momentan benütze ich den Satz:

> Dürfte ich Sie in meinem Netzwerk willkommen?

Aber ich bin mir nicht hundertprozentig sicher, wie klingt es. Für mich klingt es sehr höflich, aber Deutsch ist voller Überraschungen.

Wenn es nicht die perfekte Anfrage ist, wie wäre die Beste?

**Hintergrund:**

Die Situation sieht vom Aspekt der Etikette so aus, dass:

- Ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob ich jemandem (z.B. einem Boss einer wichtigen Partnerfirma, oder ähnlichen super-empfindlichen Kontakten) einfach eine Kontaktanfrage schicken darf.
- Aber ich will auch nicht den Kontakt verlieren. Wenn ich nichts tue, wird später sicher vergessen werden, dass er mit mir zusammengearbeitet hat.

Dieses Dilemma muss irgendwie gelöst werden, und meine Lösung ist, dass ich praktisch jenem eine Kontaktanfrage schicke, aber ich versuche es so höflich wie möglich zu machen.

Comment: Bei Ihrem Satz fehlt das Verb: Dürfte ich Sie in meinem Netzwerk willkommen **heissen**?

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach Ooops. "Willkommen" ist kein Verb hier? :-) Danke sehr!

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass sich die Einstellung der betreffenden Person zur Kontaktanfrage ändert, wenn man nur recht höflich fragt. Natürlich sollte gerade im geschäftlichen Umfeld die Form gewahrt werden (was sehr von der Branche abhängen kann). Ansonsten kann es eine gute Idee sein, der Person zuerst einmal für die Hilfe oder Zusammenarbeit zu danken.

Comment: Ich schreibe in solchen Fällen zur Kontaktanfrage einfach nur "darf ich?"
Mindestens kontrovers finde ich "in meinem Netzwerk". Es ist ja auch sein / ihr Netzwerk, weswegen ich die Formulierung nicht so gut finde.

Comment: @peterh: Wichtig: es muss zwar unumstößlich »Willkommen heißen« heißen, die Schreibweise *heissen* (also mit *ss* statt *ß*) ist jedoch ausschließlich in der Schweiz gültig.

Comment: @Burki: Mit *Netzwerk* ist an der Stelle aber deine persönliche Kontaktliste gemeint, deshalb ist es nicht auch das Netzwerk des Angesprochenen. (Allerdings geht mit dem Hinzufügen im Allgemeinen auch einher, dass man sich selber zur Kontaktliste des anderen hinzufügt.)

Comment: Etwas wichtiger als eine gute Formulierung beim Hinzufügen fände ich, dass du den zukünftigen Vorgesetzten nicht als *Boss* bezeichnest, allenfalls als *Chef* oder eben besser als *Vorgesetzter* oder mit seinem konkreten Funktionstitel (*Abteilungsleiter* o.ä.).

Comment: Ich verstehe auch nicht, was Dein Netzwerk hier sein soll. Und nein, willkommen ist kein Verb, auch wenn 'kommen' eins ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetzt kommt es sehr darauf an, welches soziale Netzwerk Sie hier ansprechen. Ich finde ihren Ansatz absolut OK, wenn es sich um LinkedIn oder Xing handelt.

FB und Twitter allerdings sind eher kollegialer Natur. Daher kommt es sehr darauf an, wie Sie zu Ihrem Boss stehen. Insbesondere, da Freunde auch Einträge von Freunden sehen können.

Ich habe es immer so gehalten, dass ich die Einladungen immer sehr persönlich gestaltet habe. Einem Boss gegenüber vielleicht eher förmlich, aber sicher mit direkter Anrede: "Sehr geehrter Herr xx, es würde mich freuen, Sie zu meinen Kontakten zu zählen."

Wichtig ist, dass ich mich danach auch dementsprechend verhalte im Netzwerk. Sicher kann ich dann nicht mehr über berufliche oder zu private Aspekte schreiben.

Comment: Hallo, [wir duzen uns hier im allgemeinen.](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/36/umgangsformen-du-oder-sie)

Comment: @CarstenS: Cool. Ich wollte nur die super-höfliche Form wahren ;)

Comment: Da war ich wohl etwas schwer von Kapee.

Comment: Genau. Es auf die Person zuschneiden schlägt in jedem Fall selbst die höflichste Allgemeinlösung. (Manche, wie ich zum Beispiel, werden sofort mißtrauisch, wenn jemand zu höflich ist! Und Höflichkeit ist auch nicht gleich Freundlichkeit, sondern kann in manchen Fällen sogar das Gegenteil sein, oder hochnäsig wirken.) … Eine Verbindung zu der Person aufbauen mag jeder Mensch. Menschen mögen sich ja, weil sie was gemeinsam haben. Die selbe Art, sich anzusprechen, wäre ein guter Beginn davon.